# Opencv; c++; Extract point cloud points (x,y,z) from out Matrix of Linear Triangulation method

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv, 3d-reconstruction

I'm trying to reconstruct 3D object in xna. I need point cloud point for that. I implemented the concept under uncaliberated image sequence for 3d reconstruction. Im stuck with  Linear Triangulation now. As a result i have value with matrix. what is my next step to get list of (x,y,z) points to draw the mesh.

Comment: My Reconstruction Pipe Line for uncaliberared images as follows 1) Matched the features using SURF and got the corresponding points. 2) Using the corresponding points compute the fundamental matrix. 3) Calculate the camera matrix from fundamental matrix (Return camera matrix based on "Multiple View Geometry" by Hartley and Zisserman) 4) Then Linear Triangulation, Opencv has triangulatePoints method. I used this method to trangulate the points. It’s returning a Matrix value.
So far this what I have implemented. Is it correct? What is my next step? I'm stuck in trangulate point matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#void%20triangulatePoints%28InputArray%20projMatr1,%20InputArray%20projMatr2,%20InputArray%20projPoints1,%20InputArray%20projPoints2,%20OutputArray%20points4D%29) of `triangulatePoints`, it returns a matrix with the homogeneous coordinate of every triangulated 3D point, i.e. a `4 x N` matrix.

Denoting this matrix as `M`, the XYZ coordinates of the *n*-th point are (conceptually)

```
x = M(0,n) / M(3,n)
y = M(1,n) / M(3,n)
z = M(2,n) / M(3,n)
```

Please make sure you understand [homogeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) before you even remotely think of doing anything with 3D reconstruction!